# Are transpositions preceeding a matrix multiplication fused automatically after graph optimization?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The [`tf.matmul`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matmul) matrix multiplication in tensorflow has arguments `transpose_a` and `transpose_b` to optionally transpose one (or both) of its arguments before matrix multiplication. Doing so let the possibility to the operator to actually not transpose the inputs (which can be costly) but simply compute the result.

On the other hand, tensorflow has a complex graph optimization algorithm that is run at each `Session.run` and looks at operators that can be optimized in the graph.

My question is, are matrix transpositions occuring before matrix multiplications optimized away automatically by tensorflow? Or should we still be careful not to overuse the `@` operator too much and use the full arguments of `tf.matmul` when needed?

In other words, even though the graph of e.g.

```
tf.matmul(a, b, transpose_a=True)
```

and

```
tf.matrix_transpose(a) @ b
```

*are* different, is the second ultimately transformed into the first when run after graph optimization?

Comment: I'm willing to bet passing `transpose_a=True` is going to be faster than an explicit op beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a small analysis of the computation times, it seems that matrix multiplications and transpositions are not (yet?) fused during graph optimization. Relying on `tf.matmul` and setting the appropriate flags is still the thing to do in that case.

[image]

*(in the graph below, `baseline` is the standard matrix multiplication `tf.matmul(a, b)`, `matmul_t` is `tf.matmul(a, b, transpose_a=True)`, and `@_t` is `tf.matrix_transpose(a) @ b`*